# the union of all the circuits and the intersection of all the bases

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

1. Is it correct that in a matroid, the union of all the circuits and
       the intersection of all the bases do not overlap?

   I susepect that is true from the equivalence in the definition for a
   coloop from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matroid):

   > An element that belongs to no circuit is called a coloop.  Equivalently, an element is a coloop if it belongs to every basis.
2. Is there some relation between the intersection of all the circuits
   and the union of all the bases?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried proving or disproving 1? Have you tried looking at several examples re 2?

Comment: I don't know how to.

Comment: Hello, I have the questions open here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/852438/equivalent-definitions-for-a-coloop. Thanks.

Comment: @Tim: Please don't crosspost with such short delay. It's rude.